# Change background color of paginate using datatable (jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

I am using DataTable and jQuery. I have a table with paginate, at the bottom of the table, I have the paginate div on green color.

I can change the paginate color to grey with this code, and I call the function after configure the the datatable:

```
function cambiarEstilosPaginacion(){
    $('.fg-button').css('background','grey');
}
```

But when I click on any button of the paginate, all changes to the original green colors. Any idea to fix that problem?

Thanks a lot!

PD: my configure datatable function:

```
function configureCountersTable(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "language": {
            "search": "Buscar:",
            "zeroRecords": "No hay datos para mostrar",
            "infoFiltered": "",
            "infoEmpty": "",
            "decimal": "",
            "emptyTable": "No hay información",
            "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Entradas",
            "infoPostFix": "",
            "thousands": ",",
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
            "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "processing": "Procesando...",
            "paginate": {
                "first": "Primero",
                "last": "Ultimo",
                "next": "Siguiente",
                "previous": "Anterior"
            }
        },
      "aaSorting": [[1,'desc']]
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Styling the pagination with css file is not an option? Otherwise you could store it in cookie.

Comment: If you want to change the style of `.fg-button` permanently, change it in a `CSS` file. That will apply the background attribute to any element with the `.fg-button` class and wont depend on your function to run